# Encoding issue when extracting edgelist with NetworkX

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, urlencode

I am trying to build the Wikispeedia graph from Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection. I downloaded the archive in which articles are "URL-encoded". The extraction from the tsv file went easy (see code). However, the first node should be interpreted as "Áedán mac Gabráin" but instead displays "%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in" as written in the file.

Python's read_edgelist doc says I can add an encoding type, but I can't find the name of the URL encoding, also called Percent encoding. I tried several from https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html without success.

I also read about `urllib.parse.unquote()` function but I thought maybe there is a cleaner way than processing the lines myself, ie an encoding name to put in the `read_edgelist()` function.

Here's my code :

```
fh = open("links.tsv", 'rb')
G = nx.read_edgelist("links.tsv", create_using=nx.DiGraph(), encoding="utf-8")
fh.close()
print("Nodes:", len(G.nodes))
print("Edges:", len(G.edges))
print(list(G.nodes)[0])
```

This is my first post on Stack Overflow and I can't figure out if / how to join a file without displaying it, so here's the beginning of the links.tsv if of any help :

```
# The list of all links between articles.
# Article names are URL-encoded; e.g., in Java they can be decoded using java.net.URLDecoder.decode(articleName, "UTF-8").
# FORMAT:   linkSource   linkTarget
#
# When publishing on this data set, please cite:
# (1) Robert West and Jure Leskovec:
#     Human Wayfinding in Information Networks.
#     21st International World Wide Web Conference (WWW), 2012.
# (2) Robert West, Joelle Pineau, and Doina Precup:
#     Wikispeedia: An Online Game for Inferring Semantic Distances between Concepts.
#     21st International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence (IJCAI), 2009.

%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Bede
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Columba
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    D%C3%A1l_Riata
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Great_Britain
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Ireland
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Isle_of_Man
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Monarchy
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Orkney
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Picts
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Scotland
%C3%81ed%C3%A1n_mac_Gabr%C3%A1in    Wales
%C3%85land  20th_century
%C3%85land  Baltic_Sea
%C3%85land  Crimean_War
%C3%85land  Currency
```

Also feel free to criticize / give advice on the form as I'm discovering SO :)